# One rewrite rule capable of rewriting multiple urls to their https (mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to come up with one single rewrite rule that checks the url string, if it contained some word, re-write it to its https version.

example: [need one re-write rule for all of these cases]

```
$http://www.example.com/account/login  to  https://www.example.com/account/login
$http://www.example.com/checkout  to  https://www.example.com/checkout
$http://www/example.com/info/contact  to  https://www.example.com/info/contact
```

this doesn't work and I don't know why

```
$RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
$RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} checkout|account
$RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(account/.+|checkout|info/contact)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Probably need something like `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` so you don't get an infinite loop?

Comment: This will work, but I have to rewrite  account/everything to https not just /login

Comment: Yes, absolutely, assuming the same rewrite rules will be picked up when executing as https.  Answer updated

Comment: can I write a rewrite rule that checks the url for say "account" anywhere in the string,[not just at the end of url] and then redirect that url to https ?

Comment: @Aresn yes, with something like `RewriteRule ^.*account/.*$`